# Find the period of $f(n)=n^{n^n} \pmod{23}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question: Define $f(n)$ to be the remainder when $n^{n^n}$ is divided by $23$ for each positive integer $n$. Compute the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $f(n+k)=f(n)$ for all positive integers $n$.

What I've done so far:
I attempted to apply Fermat's little theorem, and doing so gave me $a^{22} \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$ for any positive integer $a$. Multiplying both sides by $a^m$ for some positive integer $m$ yields $a^{22+m} \equiv a^m \pmod{23}$.

This makes me believe that there's something to do with finding $n^n$ modulo $22$. I'll call $g(n)=n^n \pmod{22}$.

However, I'm not quite sure how to do this. I suspected that the period of $g(n)$ might be $22$, but this is disproven by considering $n=2$ and $n=24$.

I also found the values of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ for $n=1,2,\cdots,7$ if that helps.

- $f(1)=1, g(1)=1$
- $f(2)=16, g(2)=4$
- $f(3)=13, g(3)=5$
- $f(4)=18, g(4)=14$
- $f(5)=5, g(5)=1$
- $f(6)=2, g(6)=16$
- $f(7)=19, g(7)=17$

Comment: Trying applying [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) for studying $n^n \bmod 22$.

Comment: It suffices to work $\pmod 2$ and $\pmod {11}$, for $g(n)$...but that doesn't help much.  The period $\pmod {11}$ is the same as that $\pmod {22}$, which is $110$ (by brute force).

Comment: Oh, it's clear.  For $11$ it's  $\text{lcm}(11,10)$ since the base is periodic $\pmod {11}$ and the exponent is periodic $\pmod {10}$.

Comment: Generally periods can be computed via $\,{\rm lcm}(m,\lambda (m), \lambda(\lambda (m)))$ where $\lambda$ is Carmichael's function.

Comment: Can someone confirm if the answer is $2530$? If so, I'll write up a solution.

Comment: You're correct, the answer is $2530$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fermat's little theorem, $n^{22} \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$. Therefore, we can rewrite $f(n)=n^{n^n} \pmod{23}=n^{n^n \pmod{22}} \pmod{23}$.

Define $g(n)=n^n \pmod{22}$. To analyze this function, consider $g_1(n)=n^n \pmod{2}$ and $g_2(n)=n^n \pmod{11}$. The period of $g_1(n)$ is clearly $2$.

To find the period of $g_2(n)$, note that because we are working modulo $11$, the base is periodic modulo $11$. Furthermore, using Fermat's little theorem yields that the exponent is periodic modulo $10$. So, the period of $g_2(n)$ is $110$.

Therefore, the period of $g(n)$ is $\text{lcm}(2,110)=110$.

We apply similar logic to find the period of $f(n)$. More specifically, because the base is periodic modulo $23$ and the exponent $g(n)=n^n \pmod{22}$ is periodic modulo $110$, the period of $f(n)$ is $\text{lcm}(23,110)=2530$.

Therefore, the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $f(n+k)=f(n)$ for all positive integers $n$ is $\boxed{2530}$.