# Moduli $m \ge 2$ such that $\{ a^a \bmod m : 1 \le a \le m \text{ and } \gcd(a, m) = 1 \}$ forms a reduced residue system

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In AtCoder Regular Contest 172, the problem [E. Last 9 Digits](https://atcoder.jp/contests/arc172/tasks/arc172_e) asks to solve $n^n \equiv X \pmod{10^9}$ for $n$ (the smallest positive $n$, more precisely), given $X$ coprime to $10^9$.

The intended solution is, first solve it in reducing $10^2$, then lift the solution to reducing $10^3$, then $10^4$, …, finally $10^9$.

The lifting is realizable because $\{ a^a \bmod m : 1 \le a \le m \text{ and } \gcd(a, m) = 1 \}$ forms a reduced residue system for any $m$ that is a power of $10$. In other words, $a \mapsto a^a \bmod m$ is a bijective mapping on the reduced residue system modulo $10^k$ itself.

My question is, can we find a pattern of all integers $m$ having this property? <s>It doesn’t seem that the sequence is on the OEIS.</s> Update: It seems that the sequence coincides with [A124240](https://oeis.org/A124240) (numbers $n$ such that $\lambda(n) \mid n$ where $\lambda$ is Carmichael’s lambda function), with only one difference: $10$ is not in A124240.

How to prove it?

Comment: Why the restriction to $a \le m$?  Isn't it plausible that the smallest solution to $n^n \equiv X$ is actually greater than the modulus?  After all, $a\mapsto a^a$ is not a well-defined function on $\mathbb Z_m$: its (eventual) period is more like $\text{lcm}(m,\lambda(m))$.

Comment: There are prior questions here about periods of power towers, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687255/find-the-period-of-fn-nnn-pmod23#comment9914449_4687255).

Comment: The main concern here is not about period, but is that why $a^a \bmod m$ and $b^b \bmod m$ where $a \not\equiv b \pmod{m}$ are not equal, specifically, for these moduli $m$ such that $\lambda(m) \mid m$, and not for other $m$.

Comment: @PinkRabbit I find this rather surprising, is it really true for, say $n=400$?  How far have you computed the sequence?

Comment: @ErickWong A simple Python script will do. Check [this code](https://gist.github.com/GitPinkRabbit/535d4943c31ab7760250c62554ce6632) I wrote.

Comment: That is a striking observation.  I find it fascinating that it resists an immediately obvious explanation.  I was not expecting to find much arithmetic structure in the sequence $\{a^a\}$, and that it would frequently have collisions for large values of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The importance of $\lambda(n)$ dividing $n$**: The unit group $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module and $(\lambda(n))$ is by definition, the annihilator of the module. In general, there is no canonical way to turn to raise elements of the unit group to an exponent in $(\mathbb{Z}/n)$. Of course, you can choose a set of representatives for $(\mathbb{Z}/n)$, but this isn't particularly interesting. However, if $\lambda(n) \mid n$, then the ideal $(n)$ is contained in the annihilator $(\lambda(n))$, so you have an induced $(\mathbb{Z}/n)$-module structure on $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$, which allows you to canonically raise elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ to an exponent in $(\mathbb{Z}/n)$.

> **Claim**: If $\lambda(n) \mid n$, the set-theoretic map on $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ given by $a \mapsto a^a$ is a bijection.

**Converting to an Equivalent Problem**: Let $a, b \in (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ and $c = a^{-1}b$. Observe:
$$a^a = b^b \iff a^a = (ac)^{ac} \iff a^{a(1-c)} = c^{ac} \iff a^{d-1} = c$$
where $d = c^{-1}$. Note that the last step follows from raising both sides to $(ac)^{-1}$. Now, our claim that $a = b$ is equivalent to the equation $a^{d-1} = c$ with $d = c^{-1}$ only holding for $c = 1$. Let the prime factorization of $n$ be $2^kp_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$. We will prove that for any solution to our equation, we must have $c \equiv 1 \bmod{p_i^{a_i}}$ for $0 \leqslant i \leqslant r$, where $p_0^{a_0} = 2^k$, by induction on $i$. This will prove the equivalent claim.

**Base Case**: The claim is trivial for $n \leqslant 2$, so assume that $n > 2$. The order of $-1$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ is equal to $2$, so $2 \mid \lambda(n)$ and $\lambda(n) \mid n$, implying that $n$ must be even. Since $c$ and $d$ are units, we must already have $c \equiv 1 \bmod{2^1}$. Now, assume that $c \equiv 1 \bmod{2^l}$ for some positive $l < k$. We have $d \equiv c^{-1} \equiv 1 \bmod{2^l}$, so $2^l \mid (d-1)$. This shows that $a^{d-1} \equiv 1 \bmod{2^{l+1}}$ since:
$$a^{d-1}-1 = a^{2^lq}-1 = (a^q-1)(a^q+1)(a^{2q}+1)(a^{2^2q}+1)\cdots(a^{2^{l-1}q}+1)$$
where we have $l+1$ even factors (since $a$ is also odd). Thus, $c \equiv 1 \bmod{2^{l+1}}$. By induction, it follows that $c \equiv 1 \bmod{2^k}$.

**Induction step**: Assume that $c \equiv 1 \bmod{p_i^{a_i}}$ for $i < s$ for some positive integer $s \leqslant k$. Denoting $m = 2^kp_1^{a_1}\cdots p_{s-1}^{a_{s-1}}$, we now know that $c \equiv 1 \bmod{m}$. The exponent of $(\mathbb{Z}/p_s)$ must divide $\lambda(n)$, and consequently $n$. Thus, we have $(p_s-1) \mid n$. Since $(p_s-1)$ has all prime factors strictly less than $p_s$, we in fact have $(p_s-1) \mid m$, so $c \equiv 1 \bmod{(p_s-1)}$, and $d \equiv c^{-1} \equiv 1 \bmod{(p_s-1)}$. Since $(p_s-1) \mid (d-1)$, we have $c \equiv a^{d-1} \equiv 1 \bmod{p_s}$, and similarly for $d$. Now, if $c \equiv d \equiv 1 \bmod{p_s^l(p_s-1)}$ for some positive integer $l < a_s$, then we have $a^{d-1} \equiv 1 \bmod{p_s^{l+1}}$ since the exponent of $(\mathbb{Z}/p_s^{l+1})^{\times}$ is $p_s^l(p_s-1)$. Thus, $c \equiv d \equiv 1 \bmod{p_s^{l+1}(p_s-1)}$. By induction, we have $c \equiv 1 \bmod{p_s^{a_s}}$. This completes the induction step and proves our claim.

**Summary**: We now know that the claim is true for all $n$ such that $\lambda(n) \mid n$, which are the terms of OEIS A124240. What about $n = 10$? As mentioned in the beginning, exponentiation by $(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ isn't canonical for $n = 10$ since $\lambda(n) = 4$. Here are some reasons why $n = 10$ working with the standard representatives is uninteresting:

- If you instead took the representatives for $(\mathbb{Z}/10)^{\times}$ to be $\{1, 13, 7, 9\}$, then $13^{13} \equiv 7^7 \equiv 13 \bmod{10}$. Thus, $n = 10$ doesn't work with all choices of representatives.
- For positive integers $n$ with $\gcd(n, \lambda(n)) = 1$, such as for primes $n$, you can always find representatives with respect to which $a \mapsto a^a$ is not just a bijection, but the identity map! Simply choose all the representatives to also be divisible by $\lambda(n)$.
- No choice of representatives is canonical, so the choice of $n = 10$ working with one choice (albeit, the "standard" choice) is not special.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you for coming up with this approach! The part "if $\lambda(n) \mid n$, then $(p_s - 1) \mid m$" is really surprising, at least to me.

Comment: Okay, maybe not **that** surprising. But it’s still surprising to step the induction with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it looks like an argument using a primitive can be repeated in each cyclic factor.    After all the group is abelian.

When $\Bbb Z_m^×$ is not cyclic,  we still get $a^a\equiv b^b\pmod m\implies a\equiv b\pmod {\lambda (m)}.$   This should be enough.

Because  now $ a^a\equiv b^b\pmod m\implies a^a\equiv b^a\implies(a/b)^a\equiv1\implies a=b \lor \lambda(m)\mid b.$  But (b,m)=1 and we assume that $\lambda (m)\mid m.$